# Can't free memory when I set the value of a variable

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

When I try to free the memory I get a memallocation error but when I try to free the memory without defining the name it works fine.

Input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char* name = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    name = "Jeff";

    printf("%s",name);

    free(name); 
}
```

Output

```
0 [main] memallocation 1434 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to memallocation.exe.stackdump
```

Comment: `name = "Jeff";` is nonsense here. Use `strcpy(name, "Jeff");`

Comment: What it does, is to overwrite the value returned by `malloc`. So you can no longer `free` it. Any value you pass to `free` must have been obtained from the `malloc` function family (except `NULL` which is harmless) but this value is not. It is now the address of a *string literal* and it isn't possible to `free` that. Instead, you have a memory leak, because you can't `free` the memory obtained by `malloc` (you don't know its address now).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because you're not freeing what you think you are.

When you do this:

```
name = "Jeff";
```

You overwrite the memory address returned from `malloc` with the address of the string constant `"Jeff"`.  So when you call `free` you're passing it the address of the string constant.

The proper way to copy a string is to use the `strcpy` function:

```
strcpy(name, "Jeff");
```

This copies the string into the memory buffer returned from `malloc`.  Then you can safely call `free` on it.

Comment: In this particular case, you would probable even use `char *name = strdup("Jeff");` as that does both the allocation of the correct length and the assignment.